# How to create objects inline for many to many relationships in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, inline-formset

I have defined such a relation between questions and tags : (is this correct?)

myproject/myapp/models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from vote.managers import VotableManager
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


class Tag(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)  # First writer of the question
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)   
    votes = VotableManager() 
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  #  auto_now_add=True  
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) #  auto_now=True
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - timedelta(days=1)
```

and I want an admin page to create `Question`s, as well as `Tag`s, so this is my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from qportal.models import Tag, Question


class TagsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Question.tags.through
    extra = 3


class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['text']}),
        #('Date information', {'fields': ['created'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [TagsInline]
    list_display = ('text', 'created', 'was_published_recently')
    list_filter = ['created']
    search_fields = ['text']

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

however, when I run `runserver` and login to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/qportal/question/add/, the page I see is this :

[image]

As you can see, it only allows me to **select** a pre-existing tag. However I want to be able to **create** a tag for the first time, while creating the question, inline. How can I do that?

Thanks !

Comment: Try take away user = models.ForeignKey(User) from Tag Model and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the inline for the tags.  Regular `M2M` field will work in admin just fine.  For more adequate `M2M` widget add the `filter_horizontal` property:

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['text', 'tags']}),
    ]
    filter_horizontal = ['tags']
    ...
```

To create a `Tag` from the `QuestionAdmin` press the green `+` sign at the right side of the widget.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't notice the green + sign until you added your edit, so extra +1 :D